# What are the steps to follow in order to run a Kaa application on Raspberry after cross-compilation of the Kaa SDK?

Tags: kaa

I have followed the instructions from http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/C++/SDK-RPi/ in order to cross-compile a generated C++ Kaa SDK for the Raspberry Pi platform.
I am now wondering what would be the next steps to properly setup the SDK on the raspberry and run a (custom, not the sample apps provided) application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else got stuck on the same problem, I solved it by copying the compiled external libraries in RPi before executing the application binary:

```
scp "${INSTALLDIR}"/lib/libboost_*.so* <user>@<RPi ip address>:/usr/lib

scp "${INSTALLDIR}"/lib/libbotan*.so* <user>@<RPi ip address>:/usr/lib

scp "${INSTALLDIR}"/lib/libavrocpp*.so* <user>@<RPi ip address>:/usr/lib
```

P.S.: That was not mentioned in Kaa IoT platform documentation for Raspberry cross-compilation.